# angularjs singleton doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

In app.js I have a variable that I use in two files/controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('appDemo', ['MainControllers', 'MainServices'])
    .constant('myConfig', {
        'backend': 'http://localhost:1236'
    })
.service('mailService', function() {
    var mail = {
      value: 'hello world'
    };
    var getMail = function() {
      return mail;
    }
    var setMail = function(email) {
      mail.value = email;
    }
    return {
      getMail: getMail,
      setMail: setMail
    };
);
```

Setting the variable from controllerOne goes fine:

```
angular.module('MainControllers')
.controller('MemberController', function ($scope, mainService, appDemo) {

    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        appDemo.setMail('test@test.com');
    };
```

But when I get the setting variable from the controllerTwo than I get the default value:

```
angular.module('MainControllers')
    .controller('EmailController', function($scope, appDemo) {

        $scope.mailAddress = appDemo.getMail();
    });
```

Each controller is in **separate file**.

what is wrong?

Comment: It's quite likely that `EmailController` runs before `MemberController`. What are you trying to achieve at a high level?

Comment: @NewDev MemberController is on a page that should bring a mail to another page where the controller is EmailController.

Comment: This may be because the service itself is being reloaded because as I can see you are setting the mail in the first controller on `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because the service itself is being reloaded because as I can see you are setting the mail in the first controller on `onbeforeunload`.

Services can't persist on window reloads or page refresh. They get reloaded hence reinitialized every time you reload the page.

If you want to persist the values try putting it in localStorage or sessionStorage.